# Pytorch: nn.Parameter to tensorflow variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to convert pytorch code to tensorflow code. I am not able to find how to convert parameter in tensorflow, I was thinking to use tf.get_variable but not sure about it.

Pytorch code looks like this :

```
def gen_adj(A):
    D = torch.pow(A.sum(1).float(), -0.5)
    D = torch.diag(D)
    adj = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(A, D).t(), D)
    return adj

self.A = Parameter(torch.from_numpy(_adj).float())
inp = inp[0]
adj = gen_adj(self.A).detach()
x = self.new_fucn(inp, adj)
```

So for this line

```
self.A = Parameter(torch.from_numpy(_adj).float())
```

What I tried is :

```
self.A = tf.get_variable(name="self.A", 
                                 shape=[_adj.shape[0],_adj.shape[1]], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(_adj)), 
                                 trainable=False
                                )
```

and get_adj function like this:

```
def tensorflow_adj(A):

    D = tf.pow(tf.reduce_sum(A, 1),-0.5)
    D = tf.diag_part(D)
    adj = tf.matmul( tf.transpose(tf.matmul(A,D),[1,0]),D)

    return adj
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone kindly give me some advice if my converted code is correct.

Thank you !

Comment: It seems it is. The best thing to do is writing a unit test that will check you get the same numerical output with both frameworks.